# Having a problem with org-roam-dailies-capture-today

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Having a problem with org-roam-dailies-... functions. My org-roam-capture-template is

```
(setq org-roam-dailies-capture-templates
  '(

("d" "default" entry
     #'org-roam-capture--get-point
     "* %?"
     :file-name "daily/%<%Y-%m-%d>"
     :head "#+title: %<%Y-%m-%d>\n\n")

("l" "lab" entry
     #'org-roam-capture--get-point
     "* %?"
     :file-name "daily/%<%Y-%m-%d>"
     :head "#+title: %<%Y-%m-%d>\n"
     :olp ("Lab notes"))


    ("j" "journal" entry
     #'org-roam-capture--get-point
     "* %?"
     :file-name "daily/%<%Y-%m-%d>"
     :head "#+title: %<%Y-%m-%d>\n"
     :olp ("Journal"))

("w" "words" entry
     #'org-roam-capture--get-point
     "* %?"
     :file-name "daily/%<%Y-%m-%d>"
     :head "#+title: %<%Y-%m-%d>\n"
     :olp ("Words"))
))
```

When I call org-roam-dailies-capture-today, using the 'l' (lab-notes) hotkey,  it complains...

```
heading not found on level 1: Lab notes.
```

That makes perfect sense, in the context of vanilla org-capture, because the file hasn't been created yet, so it isn't going to have any headings in it. But the point of this function is to **create** the file. So it has to create these headings itself and then the sub-headings and then navigate to the proper location in the file.

If I create a file using the `default' template, then go in an add the other headings, then call org-roam-capture-dailies-today and use the 'l','j' or 'w' templates, it works fine.

Am I just missing something (which is entirely possible)

BTW. the 'default', 'lab','journal' entries in my capture template are copy-and-pastes out of the org-roam info file (org-roam is v1.2.3, as installed by emacs package manager from melpa (IIRC) ). The `words' template is based on those, and, as I said, works fine so long as a use the work-around discussed.

TIA
whd
p.s. I don't have the reputation to use org-roam... tags, and I need at least one tag. So, I used `emacs'. A bit vague, but what else could I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need this. The question is 7 months old and is about org-roam v.1. But in any case.

You need to provide the headers you will use when you create the file. This can be done through the `:head` parameter.

```
(setq org-roam-dailies-capture-templates
      (let ((header (concat "#+title: %<%Y-%m-%d>\n\n"
                            "* Lab notes\n\n"
                            "* Journal\n\n"
                            "* Words\n\n")))
      `(("d" "default" entry
         #'org-roam-capture--get-point
         "* %?"
         :file-name "daily/%<%Y-%m-%d>"
         :head ,header)
        ("l" "lab" entry
         #'org-roam-capture--get-point
         "* %?"
         :file-name "daily/%<%Y-%m-%d>"
         :head ,header
         :olp ("Lab notes"))
        ("j" "journal" entry
         #'org-roam-capture--get-point
         "* %?"
         :file-name "daily/%<%Y-%m-%d>"
         :head ,header
         :olp ("Journal"))
        ("w" "words" entry
         #'org-roam-capture--get-point
         "* %?"
         :file-name "daily/%<%Y-%m-%d>"
         :head ,header
         :olp ("Words")))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've decided to use Obsidian as a PKS rather than my beloved emacs. This is because I can use Obsidian on all of my apple devices. But I appreciate you taking your time to answer.